# Wcf Singleton with Single Thread

Tags: wcf, singleton, single-threaded

Can someone explain the issues that although I set both the InstanceContextMode and ConcurrencyMode to single with max concurrent calls instances and sessions set to 1 in ServiceThrottlingBehavior, I still found that at least 2 threads are processing the wcf requests?

Client Output:

```
Client name :kk Instance:1 Thread:13 Time:2013/12/30 12:17:56
Client name :kk Instance:1 Thread:12 Time:2013/12/30 12:17:57
Client name :kk Instance:1 Thread:13 Time:2013/12/30 12:17:58
```

Server Code:

```
    Uri httpUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8010/MyService/HelloWorld");

    //Create ServiceHost
    ServiceHost host
    = new ServiceHost(typeof(ClassLibrary1.HelloWorldService), httpUrl);

    //Add a service endpoint
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ClassLibrary1.IHelloWorldService)
    , new WSHttpBinding(), "");

    //Enable metadata exchange
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    ServiceThrottlingBehavior stb = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior
    {
        MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
        MaxConcurrentInstances = 1 ,
        MaxConcurrentSessions = 1
    };
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(stb);
    //Start the Service
    host.Open();
```

Client Code:

```
    ServiceReference1.HelloWorldServiceClient obj = new ServiceReference1.HelloWorldServiceClient();
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
       obj.Call(str);
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Service Code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHelloWorldService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void Call(string ClientName);
}
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
{
    public static int i;

    public HelloWorldService()
    {
        i++;
    }
    public void Call(string ClientName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client name :" + ClientName + " Instance:" + i.ToString() + " Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + " Time:" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: you will try thread.abort.

Comment: I'm not sure your test is valid.  According to MSDN, for ConcurrencyMode.Single "additional messages arrive while the instance services a call, these messages must wait until the service is available or until the messages time out."  Try having the service operation do a long-running operation (or simply use `Thread.Sleep`).  Most likely the service is able to pick any available thread to process a request on, it can only **use** one thread at a time.

Comment: In either case, I still think you might see different thread IDs.  Also, there may be some issues with `Console.WriteLine` - at least, I know there are issues using async/await in console apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert on threading, but I'll take a stab at this and expand upon my comments.

According to MSDN, [ConcurrencyMode.Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) means `The service instance is single-threaded and does not accept reentrant calls. If the InstanceContextMode property is Single, and additional messages arrive while the instance services a call, these messages must wait until the service is available or until the messages time out.`

You're calling your service with a 1 second delay between each successive call.  Your output shows this as well - each call is 1 second later than the immediately previous one.

I believe the thread id is a red herring in this case, as I would expect the service to use an available thread from the thread pool.  I don't see anything in the documentation that guarantees the **same** thread will be used every time, and it seems to me that would be an unreasonable expectation.

If you're expecting a dedicated thread from the available threads, I don't think you can do that.  If you're expecting the service to handle only one request at a time, the way you have it should do that.

Comment: +1 - agree the _same_ thread need not service all calls. It just has to be one thread at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20833869/1529246) that *same* thread need not be servicing all the calls. `ConcurencyMode.Single` will only guarantee one thread is servicing the call *at a time*.

If for some reason you require thread affinity on your WCF service, for example, if you are running a singleton service on a WinForms/WPF application and you want the service calls to run over the UI thread only - then, you just have to `Open` the service host on the UI thread. WCF is `SynchronizationContext` aware and will dispatch calls to UI thread only irrespective of what your `ConcurrencyMode` is. Also, see [UseSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.usesynchronizationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of `ServiceBehavior` attribute.